# Cannot access azure ubuntu vm after restart

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I am not able to access an ubuntu vm on azure after restart.

This is happening several times.

Basically I created an ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM on azure and after creation I can access the machine using ssh and the correspondent keys.

When the machine is shut down  by the next start I got a connection refused:

```
ssh: connect to host myserver.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com port 22: Connection refused
```

I created the VM using an ARM template and a cloud-init file, where docker is downloaded, installed and used to start a container.

I activated the serial console and was able to see that an external data disk cannot be mounted:

[image]

I mounted the data disk using a script embedded in cloud-init

Here the relevant part of the script:

```
  # create a partition table for the disk
  parted -s /dev/sdc mklabel msdos
  # create a single large partition
  parted -s /dev/sdc mkpart primary ext4 0\% 100\%
  # install the file system
  mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
  # create the mount point
  mkdir /datadisk
  # mount the disk
  sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /datadisk/
  # add mount to /etc/fstab to persist across reboots
  echo "/dev/sdc1    /datadisk/    ext4    defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

Here is the content of fstab:
[image]

Why is this damaged after shutting down and starting the vm again?

Comment: Researching why the datadrive is not mounting is a whole separate issue, it includes questions like;

What type of drive mount?
How was it mounted using UUID or drive path?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the serial console to either fix issue with datdrive mount or comment it out in the fstab and the VM boots up.

Comment: Hi, I will try the solution, but this does not explain what this is recurrent happening. I will check how I mounted the disk.

Comment: I left a comment on the main question, you will need to review how datadrive was created and mount.

Comment: I added the code I used to mount the disk to the original question. Can someone detect any pitfall or possible problem when restarting the VM?

Comment: Try redoing you script to mount drive using UUID.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID